# Add Inline style with css variable in next.js

Tags: next.js, css-variables

Doing components for app. For section want to add ability to pass some optional accent color to get output like:

```html
<section style="--mycolor:red">
... //contents
</section>
```

where "red" can be passed in backend during page build as color name, #hex, "rgba()" or "hsla()" strings. It gives opportunity to use that color to children elements of this `section` - for border colors, first letters, markers, backgrounds etc.

Simple code^:

```html
<section style={`--mycolor:{color}`};>
```

does not work because next expects mappable code, but looks like css variables names aren't *parse-able* in inline syntax.
I can also inject it with `<style jsx>` statement:

```html
<style jsx>{`
    section{
        --mycolor:  ${ color != '' ? color : 'var(--default-color)'};
    }
`}
</style>
```

but this soluition looks "dirty" for such simple task - adds tons of unnecessary code just to serve one css rule.

I think it can be achieved with something like

```html
<section styles={myStyle}>
```

where myStyle is ***jsx*** style object, but i don't understand how to manually create it (in examples its only imported prop w/o details where did it get from).

So is there a way to achieve **simple** output like `<section style="--mycolor:red">` ?

Comment: Have you tried `<section style={{ '--mycolor': 'red' }}>`?

Answer (score 13):

@juliomalves, thanks for help, final solution is like

`style={{ '--mycolor': color }}>`
where:

**'--mycolor'** = css variable name quoted as string (css properties are not quoted !)

**color** = prop of an element

Answer (score 10):

If using TypeScript with Nextjs, there is very simple solution as blow

```
{{ ['your css variable name' as any] : your value}}
```

e.g.

```
['--rating' as any]: 2.5,
['--star-color' as any]: '#b3b3b3',
```

Comment: so should we use {{a as any: b}} or [a as any]: b?

Answer (score 2):

incase if you want to insert inline styling using style tag in next.js , you have to insert an object inside the style={} tag as all of the style and classNames in next are considered as object . For example you want to insert the background colour of your div using the insline styling than do the followings
`<div style={{ ["background-color" as any]: "#ffc107" }}></div>`
do make sure that You use semicolons to insert style properties